# Getting data from controller to the view Laravel with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get a selected product(id) from view to controller but it only shows the first product(id). So I have a loop of products which shows image of each product what I want is when a user select any image it should send the id according to the selected product. So far it only pick the first product id even if I click the last product(image) or any different image it only send the first product id. How can I fix this?

Blade

```
  @foreach($products as $product)
    @if(count($product->ProductsPhoto))
    <a  href="javascript:;" class="view-product" >
    <img src="{{Storage::url($product->ProductsPhoto[0]->filename)}}" alt=""  >
      </a>
   @else
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

Javascript

```
<?php  $id = $product->id; ?>
<script>
  $('.view-product').on("click", function(event) {
  $("#view-product").modal('show');
  $.ajax({
    url: '{{route('view.producT', $id)}}',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
  }).done(function(response) {
    console.log('received this response: '+response);
  });
});

</script>
```

Route

```
Route::get('view-product/{id}', 'HomeController@viewProduct')->name('view.producT');
```

Controller

```
public function viewProduct($id)
{
  dd($id);
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please make sure that you are getting the correct id at javascript end before actually send the id to the controller ?

Comment: How do I know(check) if I'm getting the correct id at javascript ? @Tushar

Comment: I think you should pass the product id as an **id attribute** to <a> tag and then fetch it using jquery with `$(selector).attr()`.

Comment: So I should add something like `data-id="{{$product->id}}"` in <a> tag then how do I fetch or where do I put the `$(selector).attr()`?  @Tushar

Comment: Yes, or even you can use just the **id** as well and can put it on the <img> tag and then after listening for **.view-product** class click, just do this `const id = event.target.id` and then can use it as you wish. We have to do **event.target** because we are listening to a click on **.view-product** class but we don't yet know which image was clicked. So this will take care of that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you are not sending the id on each product

you are sent the id by using `<?php  $id = $product->id; ?>` and `$product` was from `@foreach($products as $product) @endoferach`

however `$id` would be return the same id

you can send the `product id` on html and get it from javascript

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    @if(count($product->ProductsPhoto))
        <a class="view-product" id="{{$product->id}}">
            <img src="{{Storage::url($product->ProductsPhoto[0]->filename)}}" alt=""  >
        </a>
   @endif
@endforeach
```

thats how your `a href` by adding `id="{{$product->id}}"`

```
<script>
    $('.view-product').on("click", function(event) {
        var product_id = $(this).attr("id"); //this how you get the product_id
        var url = '{{route('view.producT',[":product_id"])}}'; // you cant combine js value on laravel route
        //then you need to replace it using below way
        url = url.replace(':product_id', product_id);
        $("#view-product").modal('show');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function(response) {
            console.log('received this response: '+response);
        });
    });

</script>
```